# What branch does gitlab CI checkouts?

Tags: git, gitlab-ci

How does get lab CI determines which git revision to check out? As far as I can tell, that information is not included in we hook that creates a build in gitlab CI.

Likewise, how does it determines which branch to checkout?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you [create a project](http://doc.gitlab.com/ci/api/api.html#create-project) with [GitLab CI](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-ci/blob/master/README.md#how-to-add-a-new-project-to-gitlab-ci), you would mention the "**`default_ref`**"

```
default_ref (optional)
```

> The branch to run on (default to master)

GitLab CI would fetch from that branch, and run the build script any time new commits are detected.